# Spring Integration - Missing messages while routing to DirectChannel

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

I have one DirectChannel(`CHANNEL-ABC`), Multiple producers put messages to it and there
is only one consumer of that channel.

My Application polls one folder for files in it and `CHANNEL-1` is called per file.

**Producer as follow.**

```
IntegrationFlows.from("CHANNEL-1")
                .handle(
                   ...
                   logger.info("CHANNEL-1 flow started")
                   ...
                 )
                .split()
                .handle(
                   ...
                 )
                .aggregate(...)
                .handle(
                   ...
                   logger.info("Aggregated")
                 )
                .channel("CHANNEL-ABC")
                .handle(
                   ...
                   logger.info("CHANNEL-1 flow ended")
                   ...
                 )
                .get();

IntegrationFlows.from("CHANNEL-2")
                .handle(
                   ...
                   logger.info("CHANNEL-2 flow started")
                   ...
                 )
                .handle(
                   ...
                 )
                .channel("CHANNEL-ABC")
                .handle(
                   ...
                   logger.info("CHANNEL-2 flow ended")
                   ...
                 )
                .get();

IntegrationFlows.from("CHANNEL-3")
                .handle(
                   ...
                   logger.info("CHANNEL-3 flow started")
                   ...
                 )
                .channel("CHANNEL-ABC")
                .handle(
                   ...
                   logger.info("CHANNEL-3 flow ended")
                   ...
                 )
                .get();
```

Note: All `CHANNEL-1`, `CHANNEL-2` and `CHANNEL-3` are DirectChannel.

**Consumer as follow.**

```
IntegrationFlows.from("CHANNEL-ABC")
                .handle(
                   ...
                   logger.info("CHANNEL-ABC flow started")
                   ...
                 )
                .handle(....)
                .handle(
                   ...
                   logger.info("CHANNEL-3 flow ended")
                   ...
                 )
                .get();
```

I had put multiple files in polling folder and I have observed logs as below.

For File-1 `//CHANNEL-ABC called but route after channel calling not executed`

```
CHANNEL-1 flow started
Aggregated
CHANNEL-ABC flow started
CHANNEL-ABC flow ended
```

For File-2 `//CHANNEL-ABC flow not executed and routed to another rout after that`

```
CHANNEL-1 flow started
Aggregated
CHANNEL-2 flow ended
```

For File-3 `//CHANNEL-ABC flow not executed but remaining flow does get executed`

```
CHANNEL-1 flow started
Aggregated
CHANNEL-1 flow ended
```

For File-4 `//CHANNEL-ABC flow not executed also remaining flow doesn't get executed`

```
CHANNEL-1 flow started
Aggregated
```

Sometime it skips calling DirectChannel and sometime it calls but return flow to some other channel.
I want my flow to be executed in single thread, What is the best channel choice for above scenario if not DirectChannle? And Is above mentioned behavior is expected behavior, if Yes then How can I prevent it?

**Update:**
I had added `.log` for explanation purpose only, Now I have updated the flow as well as observed result above.

Answer (score 0):

You just faced the problem with the `log()` operator in the end of flow.

See more in docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/dsl.html#java-dsl-log:

> When this operator is used at the end of a flow, it is a one-way handler and the flow ends.

That means your `CHANNEL-ABC` is going to have more than one subscriber with all those your configurations causing a default round-robin distribution strategy for `DirectChannel`: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#channel-implementations-directchannel

See this GH issue for more details: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/issues/3615

To fix the problem you just need to remove all those `.log()` operators in your flows for those `CHANNEL-[N]`. The one in the flow for `CHANNEL-ABC` is fine.

**UPDATE**

Recipient List Router approach:

```
    .routeToRecipients(r -> r
            .recipient("CHANNEL-ABC")
            .recipient("CHANNEL-3-POST-PROCESS"))
    .channel("CHANNEL-3-POST-PROCESS")
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, But I have added `.log` for explanation only. For safe side I have removed all log endpoints from the flow but issue still persist. I have update the original question with flow details and observed behavior.

Comment: You have so many `handle()` subscribers for that channel throughout your flows. The behavior remains the same as I’ve explained in my answer

Comment: Ohh I see, So any `.handle()` after `.channel("CHANNEL-ABC")` makes it a subscriber of that channel, I was not aware of the behavior. Thanks. I wants to call `CHANNEL-ABC` flow from multiple `CHANNEL-[N]` flow and also wants to handle certain business after `CHANNEL-ABC` call without getting into trouble as mentioned in question. What can be done for that?

Comment: See `intercept()` instead of `handle()` in those distributing flows

Comment: Another way is to use `routeToRecipients()` and have to recipients: for `CHANNEL-ABC` and another channel inner for the current flow. This way the same message is going to be sent to two channels without any problems. See an UPDATE in my answer.